# Anyway to obtain the acces token from Actions on Google in Header?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I developed a actions for google. Im using Oauth and Authorization Code as Linking type.

It works fine, I get to authorize my Token and everything.. but the token is always in Body. My Tutor told me that there's a way to move that token to Header so that I don't have to always read the token from body.. I develop these actions long ago.. but I read that the token is always in Body and I´m not sure if I can make that.. can someone with more experience on this topic help me please?

I created my Controller with this Information:
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/index.html

He quoted the following:

> When you have authenticated a user, the user's third-party OAuth 2.0
> access token is sent in the authorization header when smart home
> intents are sent to your fulfillment. All users have to perform
> account linking, because device information is sent to the Assistant
> with the action.devices.SYNC intent, which requires account linking.

Like I said as I read the whole documentation I never saw that I can be able to move the token from Body to Header...

Answer (score 0):

Your tutor is correct for smart home actions, but when you're using Dialogflow & Actions on Google the access token will only be available in the body.